# How I can add some text to Outlook textbox using any windows automation?

Tags: c#, winforms, automation, outlook, user32

I want to add some text to Outlook's compose mail section using any windows automation technology in C#. It should preserve its font properties, means the new text entered should be in the format which user has defined in his outlook.

Previously I was working with *SendKeys.Send()* method, but it is unreliable because their is no surity that the text will be generated or not.

I tried to use *user32.dll* and *System.Windows.Automation* but not able to achieve it.

Can anybody please help me? A small script for test will help a lot.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the COM Automation technology to automate tasks in Outlook. See the [Automate Outlook by using the Outlook object model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/outlook-solutions?view=vs-2019#automate-outlook-by-using-the-outlook-object-model) section in MSDN.

There are three main ways for setting the body of Outlook items:

1. The Body property (a plain text).
2. The HTMLBody property - allows customizing the body using the HTML markup as shown above.
3. The Word object model. Outlook uses Word as an email editor by default. The WordEditor property of the Inspector class returns an instance of the Document class which represents the body.

You can read more about these ways in [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012.aspx).

As you may see only the last two allows to get your task done.

For example, the following sample code uses the Word object model to insert a text string into the message body of a newly created item:

```
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
namespace CreateAndEditMailItemUsingWord
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Outlook.MailItem mailItem = (new Outlook.Application()).CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
            Word.Document wordDocument = mailItem.GetInspector.WordEditor as Word.Document;
            // Insert the text at the very beginning of the document
            // You can control fonts and formatting using the ParagraphFormat propety of the Word.Range object
            Word.Range wordRange = wordDocument.Range(0, 0);
            wordRange.Text = "Please insert your text here";
            mailItem.Display();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @EugeneAstaflev, I tried this code for existing new mail window.
The code is working for new mail and reply when their is a new window, where I am getting inspector using : Outlook.MailItem mailItem = currentOutlookWindow.ActiveInspector().CurrentItem as Outlook.MailItem;

But, I am not able to get inspector when user is replying within single outlook window.
How I can do that?

Comment: Correct. You need to use the [Explorer.ActiveInlineResponse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.explorer.activeinlineresponse) property instead.

Comment: I tried : Outlook.MailItem inLineMailItem = this.Application.ActiveExplorer().ActiveInlineResponse as Outlook.MailItem and but this throws error System.NullReferenceException. Simply, not able to get the item.

Also, I want to check that the reply button is pressed in a new Outlook window or in ActiveInlineResponse(Or we can say - mail outlook window). Is it possible? @EugeneAstafiev

Comment: You can repurpose the Reply button on the ribbon. Or you can handle the [Reply](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.reply%28even%29) event.

Comment: Sorry, not understood.